# Spring SQL script execution with parameters in tests

Tags: java, sql, spring

Is there any convenience stuff in spring that would allow executing SQL scripts during Spring integration tests BUT you could also pass names parameters?

`@Sql` annotations works very good however for the same set of data I would preferably wish to pass record ID so that I could have controlled environment for testing.

Point is I did not find any utility in Spring that is able to fulfill exactly that so if Spring is not up to snuff, perhaps there are other libraries that could do something like that? There are `ScriptUtils` but as far as I can tell they are meant for executing SQL resource, not interpolate query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As you see `@Sql` doesn't support. But you can create custom annotation `@SqlWithParams` and set the logic that you need. For custom test annotation you need to create a listener that handles this annotation. For handling `@Sql` spring test uses `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`. For `@SqlWithParams` you need to create a similar listener and register it.